# What is the right ToString(format) for DateTime(Offset) for the following?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

There's a ton of articles on this but I can't find exactly what I am looking for. I want to match what Java does so I think I need:

```
DateTime Kind=unknown => 2020-07-08T02:03:04
DateTime Kind=UTC => 2020-07-08T02:03:04Z
DateTime Kind=local => 2020-07-08T02:03:04-08:00
DateTimeOffset UTC => 2020-07-08T02:03:04Z
DateTimeOffset Denver => 2020-07-08T02:03:04-08:00
```

Comment: This isn’t clear at all. Can you provide sample inputs and the output you want?

Comment: Huh?  Which part(s) of which line(s) are you trying to create?  `yyyy-MM-dd\Thh:mm:ss` with an optional offset?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we at least have the input values to work with.

Comment: I was writing an answer when it was closed: You want either `dateTime.ToString("u").Replace(' ', 'T')` or `dateTime.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssK")`, and then `dateTimeOffset.ToString(dateTimeOffset.Offset == TimeSpan.Zero ? : "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'" : "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz")`

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [the `"o"` specifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier).  It will match everything you asked, except in a `DateTimeOffset` it will produce `+00:00` instead of `Z` because there's nothing in a `DateTimeOffset` that makes it explicitly UTC.   ALSO - you might be interested in [the `"K"` specifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier) for `DateTime` types - to be used in a custom format string.

Answer (score 1):

You've listed multiple DateTime formats. Which one do you want?

See (standard formats):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

and (custom formats):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

For the authoritative docs.

For your first example, you would probably want 'Sortable date time pattern': `myDateTime.ToString("s")`

Comment: I'm trying to match the standard Java toString() for each of LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime, and OffsetDateTime. I believe these match the ISO standard for displaying each.